# Set of limit points for the set of all integers.

Tags: general-topology

If the set of all limit points are in the set $E$, then $E$ is a closed set.

Suppose that I want to show that the set of all integers is a closed set. Is it right to say that since the set of all integers in the standard metric topology has no limit points, the set of all limit points is trivially in the set of integers and hence it is closed.

Another way that I can think of is to look at the complement of the set of integers, which is an open set. Hence, the set of integers must be closed.

Is there any other way to show that the set of integers is closed? One reason I don't feel comfortable about using the complement argument is that sometimes sets can be both open and closed, and the complement argument does not reveal that.

In general, what is a good way to tell if a set of open or closed?

Also, the set of rationals is not closed because the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q} \ne \mathbb{R}$. Is that correct?

$\partial E \subset \partial \partial E$

Comment: If a set is both open and closed, then it's closed. I don't see what's the problem there?

Comment: It is indeed right to say that the set of integers contains every limitpoint of itself (no limitpoint can be found that is *not* contained by the set). If the complement of a set is open then the set is closed, period! The set of rationals is not closed. It does not contain all its limitpoints, or equivalently it does not coincide with its closure.